# SQlite: issues with storing high values?

Tags: sql, sqlite, integer

In working on a project, where:

- A dataset is collected every *10 seconds*, which is stored in an SQlite file on an server.
- After being processed, the data is sent to an SQL-Database every *5 minutes*.
- Afterwards the data in the SQlite file, which isn't needed anymore, gets deleted.

The collecting of the data continues and at the moment the id doens't get reset. 
I didn't get how much an integer in SQLite can store according to the documentation (https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

In MySQL-Databases the maximum value of an interger column is 2.147.483.647. If my script would run for 10 years the id would be 31.449.600. Although this would be much lower less than the maximum, I wondered, 
**if there is any problem with storing high values in SQlite.**
Could this affect the performance?

Answer (score 1):

That page mentions that integer numbers can be stored in up to 8 bytes, i.e., 64 bits.

As mentioned [elsewhere](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue), this means that the largest allowed integer is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Answer (score 0):

An integer in SQLite can store values up to 9223372036854775807 (8 Bytes signed so 63 bits as 1 bit is for the sign), which is the same as a MySQL BIGINT (which is in addition to the Standard INT).